# python curses.newwin not working

Tags: python, windows, window, curses

I'm learning curses for the first time, and I decided to do it in python because it would be easier than constantly recompiling. However, I've hit a hitch. When I try to update a seccond window, I get no output. Here's a code snippet:

```
import curses
win = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.curs_set(0)
field = curses.newwin(1, 20, 1, 1)
field.addstr(0, 0, "Hello, world!", curses.A_REVERSE)
field.refresh()
```

The normal win window initialized with initscr() works, but the field window doesn't show up. Any help?

### Edit: Here's the new, revised code, which still doesn't work.

```
import curses

ex = None

def main(stdscr):
    global ex
    try:
        curses.curs_set(0)
    except Exception, e:
        ex = e

    field = curses.newwin(25, 25, 6, 6)
    field.border()
    cont = True
    x, y = 0, 0

    while cont:
        stdscr.clear()
        field.clear()
        coords = "%d, %d" % (x, y)
        stdscr.addstr(5, 5, coords, curses.A_REVERSE)
        field.addstr(y+2, x+2, "@", curses.A_BOLD)
        chr = stdscr.getkey()
        if chr == 'h':
            if x > 0: x -= 1
        if chr == 'l':
            if x < 20: x += 1
        if chr == 'j':
            if y > 0: y -= 1
        if chr == 'k':
            if y < 20: y += 1
        if chr == 'q':
            cont = False
            stdscr.clear()
            field.clear()
        stdscr.noutrefresh()
        field.noutrefresh()
        curses.doupdate()

curses.wrapper(main)

if ex is not None:
    print 'got %s (%s)' % (type(ex).__name__, ex)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, found the problem. When I use stdscr.clear(), it's clearing the entire terminal, including the new window. All I needed to do is make two windows, one for each separate display.

Oh, and thanks to above for curses.wrapper tip. Saying here because I can't post a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Seems OK to me -- I always use `curses.wrapper` and my terminal doesn't support cursor visibility of 0, so this is what I have...:

```
import curses

ex = None

def main(stdscr):
    global ex
    try:
        curses.curs_set(0)
    except Exception, e:
        ex = e

    field = curses.newwin(1, 20, 1, 1)
    field.addstr(0, 0, "Hello, world!", curses.A_REVERSE) 
    field.refresh()
    field.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
if ex is not None:
  print 'got %s (%s)' % (type(ex).__name__, ex)
```

I see the reversed "Hello, world!", then when I hit any key to satisfy the `getch` the program terminates with the expected msg `got error (curs_set() returned ERR)`.

What are you seeing w/this program...?  (Remember the wrapper does `initscr` and sets `noecho` and `cbreak` -- and more importantly resets it when done, which is why I always use it;-).

BTW, I'm using Py 2.6.4 on a Mac (OSx 10.5.8) and Terminal.App.  Your platform...?